# Is there an OBJ Sequence import script or add-on?

Tags: add-on, import

An OBJ sequence is necessary for making complex animations using other 3D programs. I want to use blender and realflow together.

Realflow particle simulations and meshed realflow simulations are in *.bin format.

These images suggest this was at some point in development:

[image: mesh cache seq modifier]
[image: mesh cache import modifier - could be used for all described things and problems]

How can I import an OBJ sequence?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: For now I want OBJ Sequence importer for blender in form of script or addon. Do you maybe have it maybe ?

Comment: and then to import realflow simulation from reaflow to blender that is what I want.

Comment: HERE IS SOLUTION:
http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?292968-AddOn-Import-OBJ-Sequence-As-Shape-Keys%28on-one-object%29

Comment: @JovicaŠalović This really works?